# Hybrid encryption library for text/image encryption (additional feature implementation)

Tags: python, cryptography, library

I am coding a hybrid encryption library that utilises AES and RSA to encrypt text/images, The library is working fine however I am wondering if I can make any improvements to it. I have included `try` and `except` blocks into the library to catch errors however I feel like more improvements could be made to the code to make it more streamlined and efficient.

The first thing I want to know if for my purposes, I am coding this python library to be used in a chat web-app so user messages and images can be encrypted, it would make sense to include a keystore to store the keys and/or a key management system (utilising the "cryptography" python library that I am using for the encryption methods themselves).

Secondly if a better file handling system (although this is sort of self-explanatory I would like to get someone's opinion on this) should be implemented for example using the "io" module in python to break the image into chunks then encrypt. If any references could be provided on how to use the "io" module or how to implement a keystore/key management system it would be greatly appreciated. Additionally any suggestions on how I could optimize this code would be really helpful. The code below is my Hybrid encryption library.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa, padding
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


class RSAEncryption:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048)
            self.public_key = self.private_key.public_key()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error generating RSA key: ", e)

    def encrypt(self, data):
        try:
            ciphertext = self.public_key.encrypt(data, padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()), algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None))
            return ciphertext
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error encrypting data with RSA: ", e)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        try:
            plaintext = self.private_key.decrypt(ciphertext, padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()), algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None))
            return plaintext.decode()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error decrypting data with RSA: ", e)

class AESEncryption:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.key = Fernet.generate_key()
            self.cipher = Fernet(self.key)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error generating AES key: ", e)

    def encrypt(self, data):
        try:
            ciphertext = self.cipher.encrypt(data)
            return ciphertext
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error encrypting data with AES: ", e)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        try:
            plaintext = self.cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
            return plaintext.decode()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error decrypting data with AES: ", e)

class HybridEncryption:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rsa_encryption = RSAEncryption()
        self.aes_encryption = AESEncryption()

    def encrypt_text(self, text):
        try:
            aes_ciphertext = self.aes_encryption.encrypt(text)
            encrypted_key = self.rsa_encryption.encrypt(self.aes_encryption.key)
            return aes_ciphertext, encrypted_key
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error encrypting text: ", e)

    def decrypt_text(self, aes_ciphertext, encrypted_key):
        try:
            decrypted_key = self.rsa_encryption.decrypt(encrypted_key)
            aes_decryption = Fernet(decrypted_key)
            plaintext = aes_decryption.decrypt(aes_ciphertext)
            return plaintext.decode()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error decrypting text: ", e)

    def encrypt_image(self, image_path):
        try:
            with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
                image_data = image_file.read()
            aes_ciphertext = self.aes_encryption.encrypt(image_data)
            encrypted_key = self.rsa_encryption.encrypt(self.aes_encryption.key)
            return aes_ciphertext, encrypted_key
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error encrypting image: ", e)

    def decrypt_image(self, aes_ciphertext, encrypted_key, image_path):
        try:
            decrypted_key = self.rsa_encryption.decrypt(encrypted_key)
            aes_decryption = Fernet(decrypted_key)
            plaintext = aes_decryption.decrypt(aes_ciphertext)
            with open(image_path, 'wb') as image_file:
                image_file.write(plaintext)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error decrypting image: ", e)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Hybrid encryption library for text/image encryption (additional feature implementation)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/282861/9555)

Note that any good evaluation would mean that you have a set of requirements which have been generated after a risk assessment on the assets. In this case the assets are obviously the information within the messages of your chat application. A real evaluation would check if the security requirements are met.

### Protocol

The fact that we're not discussing a protocol is saying a lot. First you should create a protocol description, and then reference it in your code. Personally I like simple versioning schemes where you e.g. define protocol with index zero to use RSA-2048 using OAEP (etc.) and, for instance, AES-GCM using 128 bit keys.

Very clearly the `RSAEncryption` class generates a key pair on instantiation. That's nice, but the main issue of any protocol is to establish trust in the public keys. So you'd have to have a trust store at the sender and a key store at the receiver. Quite often we use PKIX, i.e. X.509 certificates to create trust. Currently the whole idea about how to establish trust between entities seems to be missing, and that's actually the hardest thing to get right.

Currently you are using Fernet. Now Fernet is a pretty high level protocol. That e.g. has the disadvantage that it generates ciphertext that is base64url encoded. That's nice, but most transport protocols handle binary values perfectly well. So it is questionable if this is the best choice.

One thing that is missing as well is how the receiver will know what kind of message is being received. You could indicate a message or image yourself, but if you don't protect that kind of information an attacker may alter it.

### Security

```
self.private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048)
```

Hard coding security parameters such as the key size is probably not a good idea. Nowadays you'd try and have some cryptographic agility, the ability to use different schemes.

RSA 2048 only provides about 112 bits of security, so it is not super secure. For more security you can use e.g. RSA 4096 or for more efficiency you could e.g. use X25519 in an ECIES scheme. In that case you might also want to take a look at e.g. NaCL as protocol instead of Fernet.

That all said, you **are** using modern RSA / OAEP encryption, and a relatively modern library such as Fernet. Fernet uses a relatively secure scheme using AES-CBC and HMAC authentication over the important fields (version, IV and ciphertext). So I presume that means that you've performed some research of the primitives to use :)

The messages don't seem to get signed by the sender. That means that confidentiality is met (assuming the public key can be trusted to be from the receiver, as mentioned). On the other hand, anybody holding the public key could generate messages and send them. Some kind of signature is probably needed for entity authentication or message authentication. Any attacker can create the Fernet key, so HMAC won't save you here.

Beware that encrypting data may still reveal information about that data through the ciphertext size. Now by some luck Fernet uses AES-CBC, so you would not be able to recognize "Yes" from "No" but you might need to seriously look into what kind of information is lost through side channel attacks.

### Class design

The problem with at least the `RSAEncryption` and `AESEncryption` classes is that they are wrapper classes. These classes hide the internal details of the algorithms such as the mode of operation used. I'd argue that this functionality should not exist as separate user visible classes. They should exist as private methods within your main class.

You should really ask yourself what would happen if any user would use these classes and you'd like to change the algorithm, the mode or key size.

Similarly, the `HybridEncryption` class doesn't really tell what it is used for (it specifies how it achieves the unspecified goal instead). You've specified text and image encryption, so that should be implicit in the name.

However, that's still not really what the class does: it encrypts a string or a file. Python probably allows other data elements than text to be provided to the string method, and the file can contain any data. This also means that the class is a bit unbalanced: it provides methods that perform IO as well as methods that don't.

At the moment it is not  possible to extract the public key from the `RSAEncryption` class, so we should assume the class is for testing only. Normally you'd have to send the public key to the receiver and make sure that the sender can trust the public key. That means that you'd have one `RSAEncryption` class that can just encrypt.

In the end, for the current protocol, I'd rather create a set of `StringEncryption`, `StringDecryption`, `FileEncryption` and `FileDecryption` classes. The encryption classes would just have a field referencing a public key given by a constructor and the decryption classes would reference a private key. The symmetric keys would be part of the message received I presume, so they don't need to be stored in fields. Currently you're really

### Code

The code looks OK to me. There is an obvious lack of comments and exception handling, but I suppose that's because this is for testing only.

The Fernet keys are called AES keys, but that's not entirely true: they are also used for the HMAC creation / verification. `data_key` would probably be a more apt name.

### Performance

If you provide file encryption then it makes a lot of sense to stream the data or to use memory mapping. Reading the entire file into memory is very unnecessary and will come back to haunt you if e.g. somebody tries to encrypt a very large image or of course a video file instead.

For a chat application I presume it makes sense to stream-encrypt the data and then send the packets to the receiver directly.

As indicated, Fernet seems to always encode to base64url which may not be the most efficient with regards to communication overhead.

It's nice that you've found out about hybrid encryption, and use that instead of trying to solve encryption with just RSA, or key management using just AES.

It depends what you want from your chat implementation, but if both parties are online then creating a set of symmetric session keys that can be used for multiple messages may add more performance. That way you do not have to continuously encrypt, send, receive and decrypt the AES keys used to encrypt the data.

### Conclusion

the code seem to correctly implement hybrid encryption. The security of the generated ciphertext is probably OK.

However, the protocol and key management is entirely missing and those should be considered much more important than the implementation of RSA-AES-HMAC based hybrid encryption.